# create list of dictionary in a pythonic way

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop

I wanted to create a list of dictionary with the random variables

I know how to create this dictionary with basic python code but I'm more interested to know if there is 
a faster and more pythonic way to achieve this since I've to create this for more than 10,000 random variables

**Note:** The size of list is same as # random variables

**my random variables:**

```
lat_lon = [(42.35,-121.73),(35.67,-71.19),(38.17,-74.83)]
id = [1,2,3]
```

**Dictionary Structure:**

```
{ origin_lat : 42.67
  origin_lon : -122.67
  id: 2
}
```

**Expected Output using above random variables:**

```
[
{ origin_lat : 42.35,
  origin_lon : -121.73
  id: 1
},
{ origin_lat : 35.67
  origin_lon : -71.19
  id: 2
},
{ origin_lat : 38.17
  origin_lon : -74.83
  id: 3
}
```

**My code:**

```
lst = []
for lat_lon, id in zip(lat_lon,id):
   lst.append(
      { origin_lat : lat_lon[0]
        origin_lon : lat_lon[1]
        id: id
      }
             )
```

Comment: you don't need `zip` if they are the same size

Comment: @twodayslate How do you iterate both the list together without zip?

Comment: If you're dealing with large amounts of data, either: 1. use numpy 2. do computations in a different language (C) or 3. JIT your Python code with numba or PyPy.

Comment: Also, the first line of your for loop is using `id` twice, which doesn't make sense

Comment: This isn't much faster, but the most "pythonic" way is `[{"origin_lat": lat, "origin_lon": lon, "id": i} for i, (lat, lon) in zip(id, lat_lon)]`

Comment: numpy isn't a solution here, I'm not dealing with any computation with those arrays, I'm trying to fill those array elements and create a dict-list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Slightly nicer (and slightly faster) code would unpack completely to useful names (unpacking can unpack nested sequences as long as they're all of known length), e.g.:

```
for (lat, lon), id in zip(lat_lon, id):
   lst.append({'origin_lat': lat, 'origin_lon': lon, 'id': id})
```

Note: I'd recommend changing the name of the `id` sequence to `ids` or the like; using the same name for the iteration variable is going to bite you at some point, even if it happens to work in this case. Similarly, `lat_lon` sounds like a single value; for the collection, pluralize the name (even though unpacking means we aren't reusing it).

Of course, even better would be to dispense with `dict` emulating objects, and just make a useful class for your data; if you don't need mutability, using [`collections.namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple)/[`typing.NamedTuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.NamedTuple) will generate most of the code for you, while for mutable data, you can use [a `dataclass`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html). For an example of the former:

```
from collections import namedtuple

MapPoint = namedtuple('MapPoint', ['origin_lat', 'origin_lon', 'id'])

lst = [MapPoint(lat, lon, id) for (lat, lon), id in zip(lat_lon, id)]
```

This will save a non-trivial amount of memory too; on my CPython 3.8 x64 install, a three key `dict` incurs 232 bytes of overhead (ignoring cost of actual key/value objects), while the equivalent `namedtuple` only eats 64 bytes. Access is different (you use `obj.origin_lat` instead of `obj['origin_lat']`), but `namedtuple`s can be converted back to `dict` easily on an as-needed basis with [the `_asdict` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.somenamedtuple._asdict).

Comment: Don't `namedtuple`s also have a slight overhead? If OP wants extreme speed, raw tuples are probably better. But I wonder if this *list construction* is really the bottleneck?

Comment: @MateenUlhaq: It has a small amount of runtime overhead over raw `tuple`s, but no (per-instance) memory overhead, and it's usually worth it to have useful names, rather than anonymous indices. Raw `tuple`s are an option if speed really beats maintainability though.

Answer (score 0):

If memory is a concern you can use [generators](https://www.pythoncentral.io/python-generators-and-yield-keyword/),

```
lat_lon = [(42.35,-121.73),(35.67,-71.19),(38.17,-74.83)]
id = [1,2,3]
def get_dict():
    for i in range(len(lat_lon)):
        yield {'origin_lat': lat_lon[i][0], 'origin_lon': lat_lon[i][1], 'id': id[i]}
print(*get_dict(), sep='\n')
```

Alternative methods

```
result [{'origin_lat': lat_lon[i][0], 'origin_lon': lat_lon[i][1], 'id': id[i]} for i in range(len(lat_lon))]
```

OR
Using [zip](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) with list comprehension,

```
result = [{'origin_lat': i[0][0], 'origin_lon': i[0][1], 'id': i[1]} for i in zip(lat_lon, id)]
result
```

output

```
[{'origin_lat': 42.35, 'origin_lon': -121.73, 'id': 1},
 {'origin_lat': 35.67, 'origin_lon': -71.19, 'id': 2},
 {'origin_lat': 38.17, 'origin_lon': -74.83, 'id': 3}]
```

Comment: you are using a list comprehension here, how different it is from my code?

Comment: Check my code, I too using zip for looping together random variables

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example without `zip` as requested in the comments.

```py
lat_lon = [(42.35,-121.73),(35.67,-71.19),(38.17,-74.83)]
id_ = [1,2,3]


output = []
for i in range(len(id_)):
    output.append(dict(id=id_[i], origin_lat=lat_lon[i][0], origin_lon=lat_lon[i][1]))
print(output)
```

[You can try it on glot.io here.](https://glot.io/snippets/fk07k5ie4r)

It should be O(n). This assume `id_` and `lat_lon` are the same length.

`len` is O(1) and `range` shouldn't make a structure in Python 3.0+

[@Shibiraj's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59890054/193772) has a similar code but with [generators](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) - which is even better!